# How should my form look in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, view

I have namespaced two models. One model `Topic` is parent to the `Post` model and `Post` shares a HABTM relationship with the `Tag` model. None of the models have validations.

I would like to gather use a checkbox to set data on the Topic and Tag model while submtting the post in a single form. Any time I have tried however I run into [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269142/mass-assign-failing-and-a-hash-with-indifferent-access-rails-3-2).

Questions I have:

- How should I augment my form, controller and model to avoid the errors found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269142/mass-assign-failing-and-a-hash-with-indifferent-access-rails-3-2) ?
- Do I need to declare my namespace in each redirect_to?

*Controller code*

```
before_filter :check_authentication, only: [:new]
before_filter :fetch_author, only: [:new, :create]
before_filter :fetch_post, only: [:show, :update, :edit, :destroy]
before_filter :fetch_topic, except: [:create]

def new
 @topic = Topic.all
 @post = @user.posts.build
 @tag = @post.tags.build
end

def create
 @post = @user.posts.build(params[:post])
 @topic = @post.topic.build(params[:post])
   respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
     format.html { redirect_to [@topic, @post], notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
    else
     format.html { render action: :new }
    end
 end
end

 def update 
   if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
   redirect_to [@topic, @post], notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' 
 else 
   render :edit
 end
end

def destroy
 @post.destroy
 redirect_to root_url([@topic, @post]), notice: 'Post deleted.'
end


private 
 def fetch_author
  @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
 end 

 def fetch_topic
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
 end

 def fetch_post
  @post = @topic.posts.find(params[:id])
 end
```

*Here is my form*

```
<%= form_for([:blog, @topic, @post]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :title %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :content %><br />
   <%= f.text_area :content, sanitize: true, rows: 15%>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.fields_for(:topic) do |build| %>
     <%= build.label :topic_name, "Select a topic" %>
     <%= collection_select(:post, :topic_id, Topic.all - [@post], :id, :topic_name, prompt: true) %>
    <%end%>
   </div>

  <div class="field">
   <%= f.fields_for(:tags) do |build| %>
            <%= unless build.object.new_record?
                build.check_box('_destroy') + build.label('_destroy', 'Remove Tag') 
            end%>
    <%= build.label :tag_name, "Add Tag"%>
    <%= build.text_field :tag_name %>
        <%end%> 
</div>

   <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
   </div>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need define your namespace in each redirect_to if you want this type of nested URL. If you have not this namespace you can't have this nested URL.

Comment: thanks, any thoughts on my primary question are greatly appreciated as well.